# How much total time and resources did it take to develop stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

How much total time and resources did it take to develop stackoverflow.com? This is a great application that sets the bar for the rest of is.

Answer (score 19):

[How Hard Could It Be?: The Unproven Path](http://www.inc.com/magazine/20081101/how-hard-could-it-be-the-unproven-path.html?partner=fogcreek)

According to the article the initial coding of the site was managed by Jeff Atwood and three programmers.

The plan :

> "It's going to take six to eight
>   weeks."

The result:

> In reality, it took about twice as
>   long as that, which wasn't that bad,
>   but it was still a 100 percent
>   overrun.

And a great community website.

**Please read the entire article.**